# How to uninstall a specific sideloaded app for mutiple users from windows 8.1 through windows power shell?

Tags: powershell, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have **sideloaded** a windows 8.1 app for **mutiple users** in the device using the following command in windows power shell:-

```
DISM /Online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackagePath:”packagepath” /SkipLicense
```

Now i want to **un-install** the same app for  **mutiple users** in windows 8.1 since i want to install latest package of that app but i am not able to **un-install** the app for mutiple users in windows 8.1 using windows power shell

**This is what i have tried :-**

```
DISM.exe /Online /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName: "PackageFullName"
```

**This what the error i am getting:-**

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031


Error: 2

The system cannot find the file specified.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Am i missing anything ??

1)How  to **un-install** a specific app for mutiple users in windows 8.1 using windows power shell??????

2)What are the variousways/Alternatives to **un-install** a specific app for mutiple users in windows 8.1 using windows power shell??????

Please let me know

Looking forward for your response

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what does the dism.log file say?

Comment: Check if anything in the answers to my question here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865930/how-to-uninstall-an-app-that-another-user-installed