# Error: Registration of the app failed

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

While trying to deploy an app from Visual Studio, I'm getting an error. I have already set developer mode and also deleted the app package from the packages folder, but it still won't work.

Here's the error message:

> Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Deployment Register
>   operation with target volume C: on Package
>   App_1.0.0.2_x64__m0fsgersa29a0 from:  (AppxManifest.xml)  failed with
>   error 0x80070002. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160
>   for help diagnosing app deployment issues. (0x80073cf9)

Do I need to set anything else?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406939/815938)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me this was caused by being signed in with my Microsoft account in windows instead of the local user account. Logging in as a local user fixed this.

Answer (score 19):

I got this when attempting to debug a project from a shared folder.

Opening the project from a local folder first resolved the issue.

Comment: This worked for me too when trying to build to my shared folder on the Mac. Local folder was fine.

Comment: yes, putting solution folder in desktop then running seems solved the problem, but this is no excuse, I want to put my projects in to some folder in my second disc ..... year 2019 still we are here

Comment: ok, after upgrading windows problem disappeared, didn't note the version before upgrade but know it says v.1809 osbuild.17763.864

Comment: Work's for me, thank's!

Answer (score 16):

I know there is already an accepted answer, but I had a totally different problem with the same excact error message. When th app was running I took a look in the SQLite database with a program that I didn't close when I uninstalled the app and re-run it from Visual Studio. I think that Visual Studio couldn't overwrite the database as I was 'using' it.

Closed the program and voila the app run smoothly.

Hope this helpes anybody else as I was stuck for precious hours!

Comment: You are right sir! My problem was also with an open sqlite database.

Comment: Thanks, man! This was my issue. I had the database open in DB Browser for SQLite.

Answer (score 9):

In Windows 10 there are two possible cause of this problem are as follows,

1. Previously installed app is locked and preventing VS to delete while deploying the application. Goto `C:\Users\{you user}\AppData\Local\Packages` and delete the folder of your application. Now rebuild and deploy your application.(this was the solution in Windows 8 devices as well)
2. If it is still not working, double check if you have removed the below entry from appxmanifest file. If you are targeting `Desktop Name="Windows.Desktop"` entry should be there in the file. If it is Phone, `Name="Windows.Mobile"` should be there in the TargetDeviceFamily. You can have both in the configuration but sometimes Microsoft will suggest to keep separate configuration when you submit the application for STARTS testing.

< Dependencies>
    < TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  < /Dependencies>

Hope this help in figuring out the reason and solution for "Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed" error.

Comment: I followed as in the step 1 and first called 'Deploy' from right click on the project or 'Deploy Solution' from right-click on Solution, then, i am able to 'Start Debugging' the app.

Comment: thank you, it works for me, just need to follow the first step

Answer (score 6):

Don’t worry, the solution is actually very simple.

Error: DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. An internal error occurred.

So you’ve started your Windows 8 app development journey. All things are going smooth until one day you hit this error when trying to run/debug your app. The error says “Error: DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. An internal error occurred with error 0x80073D05. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues. (0x80073cf6)”

This is a very cryptic error and does not give you any info about what the problem actually is. The problem is that Visual Studio is not able to delete the application data in your local packages folder.

Don’t worry, the solution is actually very simple. On your Windows 8 machine, go to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Packages\ folder. There you will find a folder that has your application’s Package Family Name in it – you just need to delete that folder. The issue is that while your app is in development, it might have a random GUID as its Package Family Name, so the folder will also have that random GUID as its name which makes it hard to know which folder belongs to your app. Again, that is easy to find as well. Right click your project in Visual Studio and click properties. The value you see in the “Package Family Name” field is the name you should look for in the folder. Simply delete it and build your solution again and it will run like a charm.

Read more details at http://paraswadehra.blogspot.com/2012/12/error-dep0700-registration-of-app.html

Answer (score 3):

DEP0700: Registration of the app failed
For me the error DEP0700: Registration of the app failed, was raised because my Store App was installed from the actual Microsoft Store. I had to uninstall it and then I could debug my app smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I got this when I tried to run the project from a ReFS filesystem. Running from NTFS worked. My error code was 0x80073cfd.

Comment: This is quite ridiculous. Spent few hours fighting this problem, won't know ReFS don't work until I see this post. Microsoft definitely needs much better error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the same issue today and after a few hours I found out, that the problem was because I moved the AppIcon files into a subfolder and forgot to adjust the references inside my package.appxmanifest. Unfortunatly the corresponding error message didn't point into this direction and all the above mentioned solutions didn't help for me, so hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was opening one of the App files (Log Files). When deploying, Visual Studio attempts to remove all the files and packages (if uninstall is on in the properties). It was unable to remove the Log file as it was opened. When I closed all files, and tried again, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when testing some code in domain-bound and non-domain-bound scenarios (which requires me to have a domain account and a non-domain account on the same machine).

I found that I had to uninstall the application from the account I originally deployed it from before I could deploy it again on the other account.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that there is another Microsoft account in my computer that installed the app from Microsoft Store.

Nothing from the provided solution helped.
The only thing that solved my problem is to delete that account that I installed the app there.

Answer (score 0):

SQLlite database might be opened. Just close the sqllite and try to deploy again.

Comment: Already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34022613/2227743)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:
[DEP0700: Registration of the app failed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/dep0700-registration-of-the-app-failed-error-when/1181309)

Miccrosoft says "Closed - Not a Bug". It IS BUG, either in documentation or in message wording. It should say exactly what the reason of failure is. May also be different reasons for the same error, so the message should be precise in each case.
Anyway, I have only changed build output keeping source code on shared folder and it works.