# Universal Windows Platform - VS2022 UWP Blank Project blocked by AppLocker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Win10 Visual Studio 2022, i created a new C# Windows UWP Blank Project.

Once created i can build it successfully, but i get this error when it tries to Deploy.

Error DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073D01] error 0x800704EC: Deployment of package *xxxx* was blocked by AppLocker.

[image: Target Platform]

The PC im working on is administered by a company, do i need to ask IT do enable something or change a policy of some kind to allow new UWP C# apps to be compiled and executed?

or

Is it something else with my setup? I ask this because I can still build and execute C# WPF applications.

Thanks

Comment: note: this old thread does not help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40152760/universal-windows-platform-app-registration-fails-blocked-by-applocker

Comment: This is the document about applocker: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview This is not related to UWP but the applocker. You might to ask IT about this.