# Registration of the app failed error in Windows Store or Universal app

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Visual Studio shows the following error when I execute my Windows Store or Universal project:

> Error 1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Another user has already installed an unpackaged version of this app. The current user cannot replace this with a packaged version. The conflicting package is dff9bf13-e639-46ad-a6ed-61b27be58eed and it was published by CN=owais. (0x80073cf9)    tiles

Comment: simply remove already installed app from your testing device and try again

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406939/815938)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably are trying to install an app on your machine that already has been installed. Maybe you installed it once during development and are now trying to install it from either another account or using a different deployment method.

There are several ways to fix this.

**Best way:** Remove the installed application, e.g. using Powershell [`Remove-AppxPackage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856038.aspx) and specify the package, then try to reinstall.

**Another way:** Change the package name in the Package.appxmanifest of the app you're trying to install, compile it and install it again.

Example:

```
<Package ...>
   <Identity Name="5a0c511a-fdfd-4417-80b8-2bedbf437971" ...>
```

change to:

```
<Package ...>
   <Identity Name="5a0c511a-fdfd-4417-80b8-SomethingElse" ...>
```

Comment: I tried using ‘get-appxpackage’ like in this article https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ouc1too/2013/11/02/how-to-remove-windows-8-1-store-apps-with-powershell-when-they-wont-go-quietly/ but the app doesn't exist on my PC (administrator) and the App doesn't deploy because of the error mentioned above in this question. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Powershell command `Remove-AppxPackage` to remove the old package. If the package was installed by a different user, run as admin and use the `-AllUsers` switch. Find the package full name from the package name with `Get-AppxPackage`.

For example, if the package is `Contoso.ZiplineSimulator`, use this command to find it:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers Contoso.ZiplineSimulator
```

Then remove the package with whatever `PackageFullName` is displayed, something like this:

```
Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers Contoso.ZiplineSimulator_1.53.2912.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Answer (score 1):

### Open As an Admin the Powershell...

1- Find the package full name from the package name with:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUser
```

2- Copy the packagefullname to clipboard so you can use it later.
3- use this command as it, and don't forget to replace the packagefullname with one in your clipboard;

```
Get-AppxPackage packagefullname -AllUsers|Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

// Don't forget the -AllUsers ... then You are Done..

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and none of the PowerShell commands returned any hint the app was still installed. I kept researching and found a mention the Microsoft Store will "Stage" apps and that can mess things up. So I installed the app from the Microsoft Store, then uninstalled it from the Start Menu right click option. That solved the problem!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).