# How to remove Appx from S-1-5-18 User?

Tags: powershell, windows-10-universal, appx

For background, I have installed the app using Add-AppxProvisionedPackage, because I had the preinstall version of that. But now, I don't need that to be installed anymore.

I am trying to install new version of my appx manually using `Add-AppxPackage`, but it failed that I have the same app installed to another user although I  already uninstalled the app from the settings for current user

I found out that the appx is still installed to S-1-5-18 user, from `Get-AppxPackage -allusers`

```
Name                   : XXXX
Publisher              : CN=XXXXXXX
Architecture           : X86
ResourceId             : 
Version                : X.X.X.X
PackageFullName        : XXXXXXX_X.X.X.X_x86__XXXXXXXXXXXX
InstallLocation        : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\XXXXXXX_X.X.X.X_x86__XXXXXXXXXXXX
IsFramework            : False
PackageFamilyName      : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXX
PublisherId            : XXXXXXXXXX
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-18 [S-1-5-18]: Staged}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
```

I tried

```
Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -PackageName <packagename>
Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage -PackageName <packagename>
Remove-AppxPackage -PackageName <packagename>
```

and none of them worked.
Error varies from:

- parameter not correct
- unable to resolve package name (I tried both name and full package name)
- invalid parameter
- Error, unable to continue. Make sure that the image is installed with DISM, and redo

How can I remove the appx that is installed to S-1-5-18 ?

Comment: I found a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865930/how-to-uninstall-an-app-that-another-user-installed

Comment: S-1-5-18 is the LocalSystem (SYSTEM) account so the reference answer of using `psexec -s` to run powershell looks relevant.

Comment: I tried both `psexec -s powershell -c "get-appxpackage | remove-appxpackage"` and `psexec -s powershell -c "Get-AppxPackage -all | where name -eq "APP.NAME" | Remove-AppxPackage"`. It exited successfully, but the app is still there (which means it doesn't work). For additional info, I am using Windows 10 Anniv. Ed.