# Renewed developer license,. Now i cant debug my winrt app. Error : DEP0700

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing winrt app. Today i renewed visual studio developer's license. from then I'm getting the error. The app is running fine on simulator, but I'm trying to run it on Remote machine where its throwing this error.

> Error    1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. An internal
>   error occurred with error 0x80070005. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
>   deployment issues. (0x80073cf6)

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388586/this-app-failed-to-launch-because-of-an-issue-with-its-license),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301323/how-to-diagnose-metro-app-deployment-errors),[this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/error-code-80073cf6/072950ed-8768-4517-bd85-553fd56abd67) and [this](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2012/09/adventures-in-windows-8-solving-activation-errors/). None helpful in my case

My previous app is uninstalled & its package is also deleted.

Comment: Rebuild the app so the new certificate gets used.

Comment: @Hans the app is running fine on simulator, but I'm trying to run it on Remote machine where its throwing this error.

Comment: I got the issue resolved only after performing Refresh Tablet settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue each time I was starting my project with **Windows Universal** target. When I took a look at app manifest I realized that it somehow mentioned Win10 platform for which I could not build from my Win 8.1 box yet, I guess. I decided to simply explicitly point that I want to target **Windows 8**. It solved my problem.

[image: What to choose when creating a new project]

Answer (score 0):

This can occur for App registry issues on your computer, you can try to go to the C: \ Users \ {user} \ AppData \ Local \ Packages \ {FolderApp} and delete this folder. After just restart the computer and again perform the deploy.I had the same problem with me and was all right.